# react calls function for each item in array

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite stuck on how to execute a function for a specific post.id, and not execute it for all items within the array.

**The scenario**

upon clicking show more comments, it shows more comments for each item in the array.

For example

[image]

and this

[image]

How can i make it so that upon show more comments, it shows more comments for that post only.

here is the current code, in which the logic is happening.

```
{post.Comments.length > 0 ? (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography style={{padding: "10px 0px", margin: "20px 0px"}}>Commments</Typography>
      <CommentList  showMore={showMore} comments={post.Comments} /> 
      {/*  if show more hide show more button and show show less comments button */}
      {/* {isPost === post.id ? ( */}
        <Fragment>
          {post.Comments.length > 3 && showLessFlag === false && (
          <Button onClick={ e => showComments(e, post.id)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
            Show More Comments
          </Button> 
        )}
        {post.Comments.length > 3 && showLessFlag === true && (
          <Button onClick={ e => showLessComments(e)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
            Show Less Comments
          </Button>
        )}
        </Fragment>
      {/* ):(
        null
      )}                 */}
      </Fragment>
  ):(
    <Grid item={true} sm={12} lg={12} style={{ padding: "30px 0px"}}>
      <Typography>No Commments Yet</Typography>
  </Grid>
  )}
```

**fullCode(postList)**

```
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutlineOutlined";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import OurLink from "../../common/OurLink";
import CommentList from "../../forms/commentList/CommentList";
import CommentForm from "../../forms/comment/CommentForm";
export default function PostList(props: any) {
  const [isComment, setIsComment] = useState(false);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(3)
  const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState(false);
  const [comment_body, setCommentBody] = useState('');
  const [isPost, setIsPost] = useState(null);

  const writeComment = (id) => {
    setIsComment(isComment ? "" : id);
  };
  const showComments = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowMore(12);
    setShowLessFlag(true);
    // setIsPost(isPost ? "" : id)
  }
  const showLessComments = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowMore(3);
    setShowLessFlag(false);
  }
  const commentSubmit = (e: any, id:number) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
        comment_body,
        postId: id
    };    
    if(comment_body.length > 6 ){
        if(props.postComment(formData)){
            setIsComment(false)
            setCommentBody('')
        }
    }else{
        alert("Comment must be at least 6 characters")
    }
};
  const { posts, currentUser} = props;
  console.log(isPost)
  return posts.length > 0 ? (
    posts.map((post, i) => (
      <Fragment key={i}>
        <Grid item={true} sm={12} md={12} style={{ margin: "20px 0px" }}>
          <Paper style={{ padding: "20px",}}>
            <Typography variant="h5" align="left">
                <OurLink to={{
                    pathname: `/post/${post.id}`,
                    state: { post },
                  }}
                  title={post.title}
                />
            </Typography>
            <Grid item={true} sm={12} md={12} style={{ padding: "30px 0px"}} >
              <Typography align="left">{post.postContent.slice(0, 30)}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Avatar
              style={{
                display: "inline-block",
                margin: "-10px -20px",
                padding: "0px 30px 0px 20px",
              }}
              sizes="small"
              src={post.author.gravatar}
            />
            <Typography display="inline" variant="subtitle1" align="left">
                {post.author.username}
            </Typography>

            <Typography align="right">Likes: {post.likeCounts}</Typography>
            {/* <span
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => props.likePost(post.id)}
            >
              {" "}
              Like this post
            </span>
            <div style={{ margin: "20px 0px", cursor: "pointer" }}>
              <span onClick={() => props.dislikePost(post.id)}>
                Dislike this post
              </span>
            </div> */}
             <Grid container={true} spacing={1} style={{ padding: "20px 0px"}}>
              <Grid item={true} sm={10} lg={10} md={10} style={{ padding: "0px 0px"}}>
                <Typography align="left">
                    {currentUser && currentUser.user && post.userId === currentUser.user.id ? (
                      <span style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => props.deletePost(post.id)}>
                        <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon style={{ margin: "-5px 0px"}} color="primary" /> <span>Delete</span>
                      </span>
                    ) : (
                      null
                    )}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
            <Grid item={true} sm={2} lg={2} style={{ padding: "0px 15px"}}>
              <Typography align="right">
                  {post.likedByMe === true ? (
                    <span style={{ cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => props.dislikePost(post.id)}>
                      <FavoriteIcon style={{ color: "red" }}/>
                    </span>
                  ) : (
                    <span onClick={() => props.likePost(post.id)}>
                    <FavoriteBorderIcon
                      style={{ color: "red",  cursor: "pointer"  }}
                    />
                    </span>
                  )}
                </Typography>
                </Grid>
             </Grid>

            <Typography variant="h6" align="left">
              {moment(post.createdAt).calendar()}
            </Typography>
            <Grid item={true} sm={12} lg={12} style={{ paddingTop: "40px"}}>
            <Button onClick={() => writeComment(post.id)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                {isComment === post.id ? "Close" : "Write A Comment"}
             </Button>
             {isComment === post.id
                ? (
                  <CommentForm
                      commentChange={e => setCommentBody(e.target.value)}
                      comment_body={comment_body}
                      onSubmit={e => commentSubmit(e, post.id)}
                  />
                )
                : null}

            {post.Comments.length > 0 ? (
              <Fragment>
                <Typography style={{padding: "10px 0px", margin: "20px 0px"}}>Commments</Typography>
                <CommentList  showMore={showMore} comments={post.Comments} /> 
                {/*  if show more hide show more button and show show less comments button */}
                {/* {isPost === post.id ? ( */}
                  <Fragment>
                    {post.Comments.length > 3 && showLessFlag === false && (
                    <Button onClick={ e => showComments(e, post.id)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                      Show More Comments
                    </Button> 
                  )}
                  {post.Comments.length > 3 && showLessFlag === true && (
                    <Button onClick={ e => showLessComments(e)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                      Show Less Comments
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  </Fragment>
                {/* ):(
                  null
                )}                 */}
                </Fragment>
            ):(
              <Grid item={true} sm={12} lg={12} style={{ padding: "30px 0px"}}>
                <Typography>No Commments Yet</Typography>
            </Grid>
            )}
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Fragment>
    ))
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Grid item={true} md={8}>
        <Typography>No Posts yet</Typography>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CommentList**

```
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { Component } from "react";

const CommentList = (props: any) => {
    return(
    <div style={{ overflow:"scroll"}}>
        {props.comments.slice(0, props.showMore).map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <List style={{ paddingBottom: "20px"}}>
                    <ListItem alignItems="center" style={{ padding: "0px"}}>
                        <Typography color="primary" align="left">
                            {comment.comment_body}
                        </Typography>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Typography style={{ padding: "0px 0px"}} variant="caption" align="left">{comment.author.username}</Typography>
                    <Typography style={{fontSize: "12px"}} variant="body1" align="left">{moment(comment.createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                    <Divider variant="fullWidth" component="li" />
                </List>
            </div>
        ))}  

  </div>
    )

};

export default CommentList;
```

Comment: i think i figured it out, let me resolve this, actually i don't think i got it. :(

Comment: could you paste the method for showMore that is being passed to <CommentList /> please. I honestly can't seem to find it in there.

Comment: showMore is a state, not a method

Comment: i fixed it, ill post the code.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much just moved the show/show less logic to the commentlist component, and made this component into to a react hook component, instead of a state less component.

so now we have

Similar issue

[how to prevent duplicate onChange values within map loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614202/how-to-prevent-duplicate-onchange-values-within-map-loop/56614300#56614300)

**CommentList**

```
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from "react";

export default function CommentList(props: any) {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(3)
    const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState(false);
    const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(12);
        setShowLessFlag(true);
    }
    const showLessComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(3);
        setShowLessFlag(false);
    }
    return (
        <Grid>
            {props.comments.slice(0, showMore).map((comment, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <List style={{ paddingBottom: "20px" }}>
                        <ListItem alignItems="center" style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
                            <Typography color="primary" align="left">
                                {comment.comment_body}
                            </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                        <Typography style={{ padding: "0px 0px" }} variant="caption" align="left">{comment.author.username}</Typography>
                        <Typography style={{ fontSize: "12px" }} variant="body1" align="left">{moment(comment.createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                        <Divider variant="fullWidth" component="li" />
                    </List>
                </div>
            ))}
            <Fragment>
                {props.comments.length > 3 && showLessFlag === false ? (
                    <Button onClick={e => showComments(e)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                        Show More Comments
                    </Button>
                ) : (
                    <Fragment>
                        {props.comments.length > 3 && (
                            <Button onClick={e => showLessComments(e)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                                Show Less Comments
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    </Fragment>
                )}
            </Fragment>
        </Grid>
    )

};
```

**postList(after clean up)**

```
 {post.Comments.length > 0 ? (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography style={{ padding: "10px 0px", margin: "20px 0px" }}>Commments</Typography>
      <CommentList comments={post.Comments} />
      {/*  if show more hide show more button and show show less comments button */}
    </Fragment>
  ) : (
      <Grid item={true} sm={12} lg={12} style={{ padding: "30px 0px" }}>
        <Typography>No Commments Yet</Typography>
      </Grid>
    )}
```